# How to imagine convolution/pooling on images with 3 color channels

Tags: tensorflow, convolution, pooling

I am a beginner and i understood the mnist tutorials. Now i want to get something going on the SVHN dataset. In contrast to mnist, it comes with 3 color channels. I am having a hard time visualizing how convolution and pooling works with the additional dimensionality of the color channels.

Has anyone a good way to think about it or a link for me ?

I appreciate all input :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is very simple, the difference only lies in the **first convolution**:

- in grey images, the input shape is `[batch_size, W, H, 1]` so your first convolution (let's say 3x3) has a filter of shape `[3, 3, 1, 32]` if you want to have 32 dimensions after.
- in RGB images, the input shape is `[batch_size, W, H, 3]` so your first convolution (still 3x3) has a filter of shape `[3, 3, 3, 32]`.

In both cases, the output shape (with stride 1) is `[batch_size, W, H, 32]`

Comment: Thank you very much ! Does that also mean that when i have 3 color channels i should choose a higher number of kernels to a monocrome image ( the idea being that with 3 colors, there is more possibilities of patterns that filters could detect) ?

Comment: I don't think you need to change your model, 32 or 64 kernels is already enough to capture 3 colors !

Comment: Thank you.. and i am sure you are right. My question was more a theoretical one, that more colors should in theory warrant more kernels than a monochrome one

Comment: Yes the input data has 3 times more features so you could adapt your model a bit to have more parameters, to capture the higher dimensionality.